# fanny and kmeans clustering with R

Tags: r, clustering

Why the clusters assigned with k-means are sometimes different with respect to fanny?

```
## Data

mtcars[2:7]
```

```
# Code

k3<-kmeans(mtcars[2:7],3)

mtcars$clusterkmeans<-k3$cluster

g3<-fanny(mtcars[2:7],memb.exp = 1.2,k=3)

mtcars$clusterfanny<-g3$clustering

## Result
print(mtcars)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why would you expect them to be the same? Even if you run kmeans twice it can return different results because the algorithm is randomized.

Comment: Because `fanny` is not part of `R`, please explain what it is supposed to do.